# Unchecking radio button images

Tags: html, css

I have set of radio and image wrapped in label, and the radio button is hidden

```
<label class="col-4 center" style="width: auto;">
  <input type="radio" value="${suboption_row.value}">
  <img align="center" class="rounded-circle" src="${suboption_row.imageURL}" alt="image"  style="height:115px;">
  <h5 align="center">${suboption_row.suboption_name}</h5>
</label>
```

And upon clicking the radio button, the label is highlighted

```
[type=radio] { 
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* IMAGE STYLES */
[type=radio] + img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* CHECKED STYLES */
[type=radio]:checked + img {
  outline: 3px solid #10F608;
}
```

Is it possible to remove the highlight or border to the unchecked radio button?

Comment: Can you show us the working fiddle of your code please

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zq3ewuto/2/ here @Awais

Comment: You need to add some JS / jQuery to capture uncheck of radio button. BTW it looks like you're having only one radio here. How are you unchecking it?

Comment: @Veey sorry i didn't include the for loop, but you can check the fiddle above if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get radio buttons working correctly, it is important that you use the proper HTML semantics. First off, you should not have your `<input>` as a child of the `<label>`. Instead, they should be siblings connected with the `for` attribute on the `<label>` and the `id` attribute on the `<input>`. Also, to make sure multiple radio buttons correspond to the same value, they need to share a `name` attribute.

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="${suboption_row.value}">
<label for="radio1">
  <img align="center" class="rounded-circle" src="${suboption_row.imageURL}" alt="image"  style="height:115px;">
  <h5 align="center">${suboption_row.suboption_name}</h5>
</label>

<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" value="${suboption_row.value}">
<label for="radio2">
  <img align="center" class="rounded-circle" src="${suboption_row.imageURL}" alt="image"  style="height:115px;">
  <h5 align="center">${suboption_row.suboption_name}</h5>
</label>
```

You will need to modify your CSS slightly to make the above code have the wished visual effect.

```
/* IMAGE STYLES */
[type=radio] + label > img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* CHECKED STYLES */
[type=radio]:checked + label > img {
  outline: 3px solid #10F608;
}
```

Comment: *you should not have your `<input>` as a child of the `<label>`.*. That's **never a problem**, it is explicitly named as one of the ways you can connect labels and inputs ([*The caption can be associated with a specific form control, either using `for` attribute, or by putting the form control inside the `label` element itself.*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-label-element.html)). You only need to use `<label for="...">` if you *can't* use that arrangement, like when you are using a table and are putting the label in a different cell from the input.

Answer (score 0):

kindly add `name` to your radio buttons. Make sure it's same to all. see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/af0x9qmb/)

Answer (score -1):

**You can try this**

```
    input[type="radio"] {  //input select
        display:none;
    }


input[type="radio"]+label span{
    display:inline-block;
    width:19px;
    height:19px;
    background:url(buton.png) 0px;
}



input[type="radio"]:checked+ label span{
    background:url(buton.png) -19px top no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: This assumes that the OP has a **different HTML structure** from what they are using now.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `<input type="checkbox">` instead of radio button.